# Heroku buildpack for Meteor 0.6.5

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, phantomjs, meteorite

I've got a Meteor app working on Heroku. It uses [this buildpack](https://github.com/areed/heroku-buildpack-meteorite-phantomjs) as it uses meteorite and phantomjs for spiderable. The buildpack specifies node version as 0.8.25.

Recently, I've updated the app to 0.6.5 version of Meteor. I've corrected all the packages it uses and locally the app works smoothly. However, when I push it to Heroku, I got this output:

```
...

    Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

    execvp(): No such file or directory
    Bundled
tar: /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/bundle.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Meteor app app

...
```

I've deduced that the error is thrown by [this command](https://github.com/areed/heroku-buildpack-meteorite-phantomjs/blame/master/bin/compile#L182), which tries to use `$CACHE_DIR/bundle.tar.gz` file, which is absent (although it should be created three lines earlier). How can I fix this?